# How to create a command line tool to set up web projects?

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-scripting

I am web developer, and everytime I start a new project, I have to set up my folder structure and starter files by hand. Is it possible to write a small command line tool (Bash) that does this for me?

Ideally I would type in something like `supercommandlinetool create index` or something like that, which would result into the creation of an `index.html` file that suits my needs.

What do I need to learn to be able to write something like this?

Answer (score 2):

You should create your "template" directory structure, then when you start a new project:

```
cp -r template new_proj
```